# React Firebase prevent token expiration in axios

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a React app that uses Firebase Authentication and an Express backend.

As the idToken's duration is 1 hour, I want to refresh the idToken if it is expired.

I learnt that `firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()` will get me the current idToken. However, if it is expired, a new one will be generated.

So, I added an interceptor to Axios:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {
  await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken();
  return config;
});
```

However, I still get the error after 1 hour. What am I missing?

Comment: Hey Onus. Did you get any further with this? I tried to help with an answer below. Did you check that out, and did it make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Firebase SDKs get the ID token from the current user and pass it along when they make calls to the server, which then uses it to handle their (relatively short-lived) requests. So I'd typically recommend an approach like that.

But if you want to detect when a new ID token is generated, so that you can pass it to your backend code in a different way, use an [`onIdTokenChanged`  listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onidtokenchanged). This gets called whenever the client gets a new ID token from the server.